# ¿Como Mostrar contador de reportes registrados en mi página web?

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, php7, php5

Tengo una duda que no he podido realizar, estoy mostrando la cantidad de reportes. En mi página web, Pero tuve que volver hacer una nueva conexión a la base de datos, para poder mostrar la cantidad de mis reportes. Es decir, yo tengo una conexión a la base de datos de la siguiente manera.

```js
<?php 
class Conexion{   
    public static function Conectar() {        
        define('servidor', 'localhost');
        define('nombre_bd', 'sanandre_cmaps');
        define('usuario', 'root');
        define('password', '');                             
        $opciones = array(PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES utf8');            
        try{
            $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=".servidor."; dbname=".nombre_bd, usuario, password, $opciones);            
            return $conexion;
        }catch (Exception $e){
            die("El error de Conexión es: ". $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Lo que hace el siguiente codigo, es mostrar la cantidad de reportes que estan registrados
[image: Reportes]

El problema que tuve que realizar otra conexion porque no me mostraba nada si incluia la conexion existente.

```js
 <?php
 php $con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "sanandre_cmaps");
                            $query = "SELECT id FROM reportes WHERE estatus = 1"; 
                            $query_run = mysqli_query($con, $query);
                            $row = mysqli_num_rows($query_run);
                            echo '<h4> Total: '.$row.'</h4>';
                            ?>
```

Lo que quiero saber es como puedo reutilizar la conexion principal sin volver a tener que crear una nueva conexio, no se si me entiendan.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En cada clase que necesites de la conexión hazle un `require_once`; supongamos en tu clase X declaras la variable privada conexión y de ahí en más empiezas a crear tus métodos, el primero será el constructor, ahí agregas algo así:

```
private $conexion;
        function __construct()
        {
            require_once './Conexion.php';
            $this->conexion = new Conexion();
            $this->conexion->Conectar();
        }
```

Comment: @Isanchezo me manda error al crearlo.